# How to load sampled image from Uri?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I need to load image with reduced resolution. How can I do this?

I tired next code:

```
public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(@NonNull Uri Uri, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    try {

        InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri);

        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);   // I can read width and height from options

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
    } catch (Exception ignored)
    {

    }
    return null;
}
```

And I even can see the width and height of loaded image. But `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` returns `null` when I turned `inJustDecodeBounds` to false. Whats wrong?

The image selected by user from gallery. All permissions granted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `InputStream` was closed by the first `decodeStream()`. Open a fresh `InputStream` for use with the second `decodeStream()`.